# jQuery - Get content of clicked element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

i tried to get the id of the clicked element of a jquery mobile list:

```
<div data-role="main" id="immals">
 <ul data-role="listview" class="immj ui-listview" id="imj">
    <li class="ui-first-child"><a href="#stdjg" id="test">TEST</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#stdjg11" >11</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#stdjg12" >12</a></li>
    <li class="ui-last-child"><a href="#stdjg13">13</a></li></ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(data) {
    $('#imj li').click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr('itemid'));
    });
});
```

But I always get "undefined"

Comment: You're not declaring any attributes by the name of `itemid` in your HTML.

Comment: And none of the `li` elements (which will be `this` in the code) have any `id` set, either.

Comment: **jQuery Mobile** does not use **DOM ready**; there are several other events you can use. Having said are you looking to get the contents or the id of the element clicked. Bear in mind that jQuery Mobile modifies your markup, so if you're trying to get the contents, brace yourself -- you'll get more than you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

your `$('#imj li')`'s dont have suche itemid attribute, to retrieve the content use .html()

```
$(document).ready(function(data) {
$('#imj li').click(function(){
  alert($(this).html())
});
});
```

Comment: @War10ck lol at the moment i read this i saw in the question title that he wants to retrieve the conten -.- what a bad formulated and prepared question

Answer (score 1):

There is no such attribute to find the value for

```
$('#imj li').click(function() { // click on list item for ul of id imj
  alert($(this).attr('itemid')); // get the list item's attribute itemid
});
```

***Crash!*** There is no such attribute in your HTML markup, jQuery was not able to complete the request and you'll scratch your head, for why, why why jQuery why! But, that won't work. You need to understand the jQuery code here.

You will get the attribute value, of the attribute (whose string name) you're actually passing to the method. Then the value would be used as a `string` variable to be alerted.

This can do the trick for you. *Just example*, note that there is no such attribute as `itemid`.

```
<li itemid="something">List Item content</li>
```

Then the code would work. Otherwise it won't work as you *want* it to work.

What you should try, would be like this

```
<li id="itemid1">Item id is 1!</li>
```

Comment: There's no such attribute as `itemid`. You should use a valid attribute like `id` or create a custom `data-*` attribute like `data-itemid`...

Comment: ah my fault, i write itemit after <li> and not in the <li>

Comment: @War10ck I know that. :) I was just trying to be at easy with him. Nothing else, however I have added that example part too.

Comment: Another Question:
The function: 
$('#imj li').click(function()
only works with the predefined listelements, the dynamic added doesn't work..
The code for this is:
$("#immals ul").append("<li itemid="+data.jahr[i]+"><a href=#stdjg>"+data.jahr[i]+"</a></li>");

So whats wrong?

Comment: @user3772619 You'll need to use event delegation with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) depending on your jQuery version...

Comment: so i write:
$('#imj').on('click',function(){
  alert($(this).attr('itemid'));
  stdjg=$(this).attr('itemid');
  alert(stdjg); 

so the alerts come but the attr itemid does not work longer :(